# plot data frame in R

Tags: r, plot

I want to plot some data in R. However, when I try to plot my dataframe "bef_ads", a large number of plots are shown together. I just want to get the list inside the data frame and make a normal plot.

Thanks!

```
dput(bef_ads)
structure(list(V1 = 56660L, V2 = 60616L, V3 = 85913L, V4 = 70709L), 
 .Names = c("V1","V2", "V3", "V4"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `plot(bef_ads)` will give you a pairs plot, a common tool for looking for visual correlation or comparison of each pair of variables within the data frame. Since your data has four columns, you get `n*(n-1) = 12` plots, 6 unique with the other 6 just axis-swapped. When you say "get the list," what desired output do you expect? When you say "make a normal plot," again, can you describe what *one plot* you are expecting to get?

Comment: Do you just want `barplot(unlist(bef_ads))` or `plot(unlist(bef_ads),type="l")`? `plot()` gives different results depending on the type of object you pass to it, as @r2evans implies.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your data is in different columns of a data frame with 1 row. When you use `plot(...)` on this, it treats each column as a different dataset (with just one point, in your case). This is why you are getting all those plots.

So you could transpose the dataframe (to one with one column and 4 rows), and plot that:

```
plot(t(bef_ads),type="b")
```

[image]

Or you could "unlist" the data frame as suggested in a comment. This basically converts the data frame to a vector and plots that.

```
plot(unlist(bef_ads),type="b")
```

Answer (score 0):

For a barplot:

```
barplot(unlist(bef_ads))
```

[image]

Comment: Saving the plot itself is probably better than taking a screenshot.